# $(location).attr('href',url); is not working in ios devices

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, ios7

```
url="page2.html";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

is not working in ios devices.
my scenario is to redirected to the page2.html
all mobile and browser are working except ios devices.
i tried many other options but all are helpless

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect `$(location).attr('href',url);` to work on any device... did you try `window.location.href = url;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make vanilla js jQuery. Don't do that.

```
var url = "page2.html";
window.location.href = url;
```

That's what you need to run.

Note, however, that the browser may block this if you merely call it without some sort of user interaction.

Comment: var url = "page2.html";
window.location.href = url; this is not working i tried in iphone 5s with user intraction